# How to protect some files against an application on user level?

Tags: ubuntu, security, file-permissions

On multi-user Ubuntu system, how can I give my users a way to execute downloaded applications in a way, that the application doesn't have access to all files except specified whitelist (which is different for each application), and which doesn't (much) increase system resources?

Some users download and "install" (which means unpack in ~/bin) lots of applications. The objective is to run these applications in a way that these applications can access only user-specified directories with application-specific configuration, working data, etc., but not shh keys, private photos, internal data of other such applications, etc. Each application should have it's own whitelist.

But these users are not allowed to modify the system nor access other users' files. (I.e. these users must not receive root rights. They're not administrators.)

Comment: Sandboxing ALWAYS has overhead. Sandboxing requires some form of virtualization, which means overhead. Sandboxing in its various forms is also perhaps the only way to do what you require.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote "...not increasing (**much**) system resource usage...". Correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK sandboxing doesn't have as huge overhead as virtualization of whole OS. To give better example (or see original question if you can access edit history), I want to use it for some of everyday apps, like Skype - in total 10-20. Small overhead is OK in this count (when compared with thousands of processes) AFAIK, VirtualBox would kill the system.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you use different user accounts, but then I saw (in the revision history) that you have already considered that.  It’s very low overhead.  (1) You have to create the “sandbox” account, which takes a minute or two, but you need to do this only once.  (Once per application, if you’re really paranoid, and you want each app in a separate sandbox, so they can’t interfere with each other.)  (2) A few milliseconds to start the app with `su` or `sudo`.  (You will probably want to define an alias or other wrapper to do this automatically.)

Comment: Problem (one of the problems) is, I cannot respond to people in Skype/Discord and I'm not notified by Thunderbird, when it's run from different account than I'm currently in... Even if I switch with ctrl+alt+FX and run another X session with startx, the notifications and sounds are (correctly) blocked when I'm in different terminal.

Comment: Ignore my previous commit, I guess I'm tired, it doesn't make sense with you su/sudo suggestion. It's interesting, but quite inconvenient from different reasons: synchronization with Unison (with my laptop) and there are apps I trust little bit more (like midnight commander) which should have access to most of the data...

Answer (score -1):

[AppArmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) seems to be exactly what you are after: from Wikipedia:

> AppArmor ("Application Armor") is a Linux kernel security module that allows the system administrator to restrict programs' capabilities with per-program profiles. Profiles can allow capabilities like network access, raw socket access, and the permission to read, write, or execute files on matching paths.

AppArmor is a default install on Ubuntu, and there are profiles in place for some applications (Firefox, for instance).

There is a Wiki [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/apparmor.7.html). You can look at profiles already defined on your system (`etc/apparmor.d`), but avoid the Firefox one which is more complex than most.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you, please, provide links (or elaborate) _how to use it in user-space_? When I was searching for the solution (before I created this question), I encountered the AppArmor, however, _I was unable to find any information_ about using it in the user-space.

Comment: What do you lean by "use it in user-space"? Use it without root privs? You only need the privs when setting up the armor....

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Thing is, trying new applications (installed in home directory without need of root privileges) is quite usual part of my workflow. I'm trying to avoid doing any step of that as a root, for security reasons.

Comment: Simplest way is a virtual box, then. A Linux VBox isn't that heavy, especially is you pick up a light weight distro (Lubuntu or else), and remove all the stuff which isn't useful in a Vbox.

Comment: Considering what I wrote about Virtual Box in both original and edited question... does that mean the answer to my question is "under these constraints - there is no way"?

Comment: Your initial question didn't state that 1) you didn't want to use root privs, and 2) that it would be to test software (instead of running the same few apps in a protected fashion).

Comment: @xenoid I apologize for that and I don't know what to do with that. My really first (really initial) question tried to be as clear as possible. But it was marked as "too broad" without [explanation](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13311/943030) what's the exact problem. So I shortened it (i.e. omitted all the details and left the most basic core), but now I need to refine all the aspects when someone suggests something which doesn't quite work with _actual_ problem. And btw. it's not quite about _testing_ apps, it's more about _using_ them. E.g. I want isolate Skype - always.

Comment: @xenoid To be more specific about _testing_ and _using_ apps - I apologize, when I wrote " trying new applications ... is quite usual part of my workflow", I didn't make myself quite clear. What I was trying to say is, that set of applications I use for work is ever changing. I encounter a new problem. Try a few applications. Select the one that solves my problem the best, but I _still_ want to keep it isolated (in most cases). Or some of the applications I use becomes obsolete. For example lately I'm really thinking about replacing Dropbox.

Comment: @xenoid The point is, yes, this question is about isolating apps which I _use_ in everyday work. But problem is, the set of applications is _not constant_. A very simple example: I play games. There are _always_ new games. So the solution I'm looking for shouldn't require root privs, because it's something I do _regularly_ and I'm (generally) trying to avoid workflow which requires _absolute_, root rights for everyday work of single user - me. What I'm trying to do is _affect single user, myself_, not to _change system_.

Comment: @xenoid In other words, the problem which I'm trying to solve by avoiding using root privs is to avoid a system, which can be used _only if I'm constantly logged as root_. Like at Windows XP times where you _had_ to be an admin if you want actually use the system for most operations. 

But, of course, I'm absolutely OK with using root privs to actually install the SW or configure the system to allow me to isolate apps.

Comment: "*But, of course, I'm absolutely OK with using root privs to actually install the SW or configure the system to allow me to isolate apps.*" Then, as stated above, apparmor requires rootprivs for setup, not for each execution of the app.

Comment: @xenoid When - as a standard user - I download new game or app, install it to ~/bin/, does it allow me to configure it for this new executable without root privs? (Just for me, a single user.)

Comment: @xenoid Btw. am I really so hard to understand? As a non-native English speaker, I really try to write simple sentences, empathise to core points, but it seems I really fail to explain my point...

Comment: @xenoid OK, what about example: as a root I install ssh and ssh server (step #1). As a root I _configure_ the ssh server (port, enable x-forwarding, etc.) (step #2). Then, as a _user_ I can create new keys, add public keys, configure aliases, etc. In other words, I can _configure the ssh in user-space without need of root privs_ (step #3). I don't need access to _everything_ to just generate a key. Then, as a user, I can use ssh to connect (step #4). So what I'm looking for is to something **like** App Armor which allows me to configure app limits for me, user, as a step #3 - non-root.

Comment: @xenoid Another way to look at my problem: I'm administrator of a multi-user PC. I want to allow some users to download apps from Internet, configure the-solution-I'm-looking-for-which-limits-access-to-the-app and execute the application with configured limits. However, I don't want these users to be able to access files of other users (including all with this ability), I don't want these users to be able to change system configuration and definitely, I don't want them to be able configure the-solution-I'm-looking-for for other users. That's what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: May I suggest that you rework your initial question to include all this information?

Comment: @xenoid OK, I did my best to reflect that in the question without getting too broad.